# Problems with scaling then running XNA game on Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, xna, xna-4.0

I have JUST finished my own great brick-breaker type game.

I've been working on it on and off for 2 years, so I am pretty serious about it.

And I could go on for a long time about cool features, such as 20 power-ups,
bricks of infinite variety, light fx, particle systems, dynamic bricks, menu systems, etc.
But I won't, because it all works perfectly - on a regular windows 7 machine, with .Net 4.0 
and XNA 4.0...

Now, I've learned everything by myself (from places like this), including of course `c#`, `xna`, `gimp`, `fl-studio`, some 'new-to-me' trigonometri, etc, so please do not assume that I am simply too lazy to look around for an answer.

-But I can't find anything online on the issues I'm having with windows 8, and I'm guessing others may be having, or have had, similar issues.

Now, I can install the xna redist. on win 8, and run my game in desktop mode - As it should be -
But there are strange near-game-breaking issues.

I guess I'll start with one of them:

`1) My brick light sprites are completely off-scale compared to everything else, all my other sprites scale just fine, like the background-sprite, brick-sprites themselves and the ball/paddle sprites.`

How is a subset of sprites suddenly not scaled when all the others are?
They all have similar or identical draw methods, afterall.

Why would windows 8 be selective like that? Everything scales perfectly on win7.

`2) I have a small program included, non-xna, simple win-form thing, to configure the graphics settings outside the game. It includes 3 drop-down menus for resolution choices under various aspect-ratios. However, only on windows 8, ONLY ONE of these drop-down lists (The by-default selected 16:9 one) will not accept input, while the others will.`

It's like windows 8 picks a few NON special and rather trivial items, and screws them up, while leaving the others intact.

`But shouldn't win8 easily support .NET 4.0 winform control stuff?` I would think so.

Now, I have read about mono-game. But I dont care about metro/tile-stuff, and I dont plan to develop on a win8 machine either, which are the only real arguments I've found for using it in MY case. I just want the
game to run without error, and that should be doable with XNA, right?

**I havent found any documentation saying that people's XNA games are suddenly un-playable because "windows 8".**

Any tips or answers would make my base belong to you.

Comment: Could you possibly show code that not performing well on Windows 8? Does it reproduces on an example app?

Comment: Well, since i develop in win7 and not win8, I cant actually follow the code as it is being run... But judging from what I see, it seems that SOME sprites (my semi-transperant radial-gradient sprites) are drawn at a wrong scale..!

Comment: EDIT: Well, since I develop in win7, 
I cant actually follow the code as it is being
run on win8 where the scaling-problem occurs.
So I dont have the knowledge at this time to pin-point relevant code.
But I SHOULD be able to run xna games in desktop mode, right?
Im not crazy?
-Also, regarding the non XNA tools I made, shouldnt winforms that
work on win 7 automatically work for win8, no adjustment needed?
Or does .net 4.5 read things differently than the 4.0 I developed for?

Comment: Well, could you possibly create a sample project with issue so someone on Windows8 could try to reproduce the bug? However it would be much more efficient to try it on Windows 8 by yourself! I guess it's really useless to wait to someone actually will **try** to reproduce that bug for you.

Comment: No you are not crazy, I guess it's normal to expect that XNA game and app should work the same in Win7 and Win8.

Comment: Thanks Petr... Maybe it has more to do with the target machine being a lap-top than a windows 8 machine..? Or some kind of graphic card scaling-hardware stuff that I dont understand..! Although I doubt that... Perhaps its time to start barking up the mono-game tree, like so many XNA-folks before me... Sheeesh this whole game-dev thing is a mess..! -Cant wait for AI to come along and program games for me, based on my specifications...

Comment: @user3508958, Then we would all be out of a job :(

Comment: I also think Monogame would not hurt. If you only want to run on the Windows Desktop, porting should be really easy and I have ahd no issues with Monogame on any platform I used it on (Desktop, Windows RT, Windows Phone and Android).

Comment: @user3508958 Can you also verify that the issue is not caused by Windows' high DPI support? I used different properties to get the width (graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth and Windows.Width) and if the scaling is set to more than 100%, they are not necessarily the same.